# Unwrap optional string array in Swift

Tags: swift

The code below fails to compile at the last line: "Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments."

How do I fix the code without changing the type for items?

```
class Test {
    var items:String[]?

    func process() {
        if (self.items == nil) {
            self.items = String[]()
        }

        for i in 1...5 {
            var item =  String(i)
            self.items! += item
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not figured out a way to append to an optional array. I don't believe that is possible. You can achieve a similar effect to what your code is attempting to do by doing this:

```
class Test {
    @lazy var items = [String]()

    func process() {
        for i in 1...5 {
            var item =  String(i)
            self.items.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I already submitted a bug to Apple about this issue

Comment: I would like to instantiate items lazily, right before adding the first element.

Comment: And if one doesn't want to create the array until later, declare it with `@lazy`.

Comment: @Boon, with GoZoner's suggestion, you are achieving exactly that

Comment: With GoZoner's method, items is not Optional though right? So looks like there is no way to achieve lazy instantiation if we have an Optional Array?

Comment: @Boon I don't believe so, no

Answer (score 1):

Create it lazily:

```
class Test {
  @lazy var items = String[]()
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following will keep items as an optional array while maintaining the general flow:

```
class Test {
    var items : String[]?

    func process() {
        var items = self.items ? self.items! : String[]()

        for i in 1...5 {
            var item =  String(i)
            items += item;
        }

        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't arrays copied on assignment?  This results in two copies every time `process()` is called (except for the first time when the empty array is created).

Comment: They're lazily copied on assignment (they're not really copied until you change their size) but then again, they're also copied when you append items, so you're really copying the array 5 times every time through, no matter how you do it.

Comment: Well, not really "no matter how" you could minimize it by creating a single array of 5 strings and then appending that to the existing items array, that would only copy the array once per execution.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

In the version of Swift provided with Xcode 6 Beta 5, the bug is fixed and the code runs normally (after adaptation, of course), here's the new code:

```
class Test {
    var items:[String]?

    func process() {
        if (self.items == nil) {
            self.items = [String]()
        }

        for i in 1...5 {
            var item = String(i)
            self.items!.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Old Answer

<strike>I have found that the result of **unwrapping** is a **constant**, and a **constant** can't be **mutated**. Thus the error "Could not find an overload for '+=' that accepts the supplied arguments." since the operator '+=' is defined as:</strike>

`@assignment func +=<A : ArrayType>(inout lhs: A, rhs: A._Buffer.Element)`

So as solution you can either use `@lazy` attribute *(as suggested by GoZoner and seen in drewag's answer)* or David's method of creating a temporary variable.

#### Method 1 (`@lazy`):

Taken from drewag's answer

```
class Test {
    @lazy var items = String[]()

    func process() {
        for i in 1...5 {
            var item =  String(i)
            self.items.append(item)
        }
    }
}
```

#### Method 2 (temporary variable):

Taken from David's answer

```
class Test {
    var items : String[]?

    func process() {
        var items = self.items ? self.items! : String[]()

        for i in 1...5 {
            var item =  String(i)
            items += item;
        }

        self.items = items
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do you show via code that unwrapping is a constant?

Comment: Also, if the result of unwrapping is a constant, why would David's unwrapping work?

Comment: @Boon the only way to prove that unwrapping is a constant, is by trying the operations on a constant which will give the same error.
Ex.
    `let items = String[];`
    `items += "a"`

Comment: @Boon David's unwrapping works because he is unwrapping into a variable (`var items`) and as `items` is not a constant he can do all the normal operations

Comment: Thanks @Ziad - what's the difference between String[]? vs [String]?

Comment: You're welcome @Boon, Swift is still changing and one of those changes is the type syntax for arrays, `String[]` is now written as `[String]`